# Span doesn't fit in another span

Tags: html, css

i try to fit span in another span but for some reason it doesnt work.

I have already tried `display: flex` and `display: flexbox`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch12mpe3/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#midbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background-color: #7d7c7d;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  position: relative;

  height: 100%;
  width: 35%;

  background-color: #525052;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#preview p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3%;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0.7;

  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;

  height: 100%;
  width: 35%;

  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<span id="midbox">
  <span id="preview">
    <p>Preview</p>
  </span>
  <span id="cont">
    <p>Why does this apper under the box and not on the left?</p>
  </span>
</span>
```

## Expectation:

Content of span with green background should be inside the lightgray box.

## Output:

Content of span with green background is outside of any box.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding float:left; to both your #preview span and #cont span. Float left forces two elements to stay on the left side.

```
#preview, #cont{
  float:left;
}
```

I updated your fiddle. Try the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/edy0whkp/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make `#preview` and `#cont` sit side by side within `#midbox`. If this is the case, simply make `#midbox {display: flex;}`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#midbox {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #7d7c7d;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: #525052;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#preview p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3%;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<span id="midbox">
  <span id="preview">
    <p>Preview</p>
  </span>
  <span id="cont">
    <p>Why does this apper under the box and not on the left?</p>
  </span>
</span>
```

If you want to learn about flexbox there's a great article at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

You're setting `display: block` to your span elements. This turns them into block elements which start on a new line and they expand the size of their parent container. Changing the display to `dispay: inline-block` will cause the elements to *not* start a new line and to only take up as much space as they need.

https://jsfiddle.net/xypntkc0/

### More details

In the JSFiddle I changed the parent element to be a `div` instead. Setting it to a div makes it a block component so you also don't need the `display: block` when it's a div. It's bad practice to place block elements inside of inline elements (you have a paragraph tag as a child tag to your span tags) So I would actually change all your span tags to `divs`

I also changed the position to `position: relative` on the parent component. You typically only want to set `absolute` to the children elements inside of a parent component that has `position: relative`. The parent is set as relative so that their absolute positioned children get positioned *relative* to the parent.

### Even more detail

If you want to align elements next to each other inside of a container, a good tool to use is flexbox. You can set `display: flex` to the parent element to mark it as a flex container. Then the children will automatically be set as flex items and will render side by side and boom, you're done.
https://jsfiddle.net/vkru8wg7/